# ViewModel has no zero Argument constructor. Have AndroidEntryPoint

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

Hey all I am having problems figuring out hilt with android. Ive googled around and I can't find this specific problem.  I seem to getting a "View Model has no zero argument constructor". I saw on another post that it was for a missing @AndroidEntryPoint annotation in their main activity however I added that and at this point I am a little stumped.

So far I have an application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class RecipeApplication: Application() {
}
```

The main activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = primaryBackgroundColor
                ) {
                    RecipeBookApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The View model

```
@HiltViewModel
class RecipeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val recipeRepo: RecipeRepo
) : ViewModel() {....}
```

and then the Composable setting up my UI.

```
@Composable
fun RecipeBookApp(
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    Log.d("GetRecipe", "Still in Recipe Screen About to make the call")

    val recipeViewModel = viewModel(modelClass = RecipeViewModel::class.java)

    var editMode by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Scaffold(
        backgroundColor = primaryBackgroundColor,
        topBar = {
            val title = "Edit"
            Column {
                Row(Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                    NiceButton(title = title) {
                        editMode = !editMode
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
        }) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController,
            RecipeScreen.Start.name
        ) {
            composable(route = RecipeScreen.Start.name) {
                RecipeGridScreen(
                    onGridButtonClick = {
                        navController.navigate(RecipeScreen.RecipePage.name)
                    }
                )
            }
            composable(route = RecipeScreen.RecipePage.name) {
                val state = recipeViewModel.recipeState.collectAsState()
                RecipeView(state.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeRepo

```
class RecipeRepo @Inject constructor(
    private val recipeApi: RecipeApi
    ) {
    suspend fun getAllRecipes(): RecipeList {
        return recipeApi.getRecipes()
    }
}
```

RecipeApi

```
interface RecipeApi {
    @GET("recipe/getRecipes")
    suspend fun getRecipes(): RecipeList
}
```

RecipeApiModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RecipeApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(builder: Retrofit.Builder): RecipeApi {
        return builder
            .build()
            .create(RecipeApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RECIPE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    }
}
```

> Process: com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe, PID: 6287
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
> com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe.ui.recipe.RecipeViewModel
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
> at
> com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe.ui.RecipeGridScreenKt.RecipeGridScreen(RecipeGridScreen.kt:30)
> at
> com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe.ui.recipe.RecipeScreenKt$RecipeBookApp$2$1$1.invoke(RecipeScreen.kt:63)
> at
> com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe.ui.recipe.RecipeScreenKt$RecipeBookApp$2$1$1.invoke(RecipeScreen.kt:62)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
> at
> androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
> at
> androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:73)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:13)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:10)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
> 2023-02-04 11:45:31.431  6287-6287  AndroidRuntime
> com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe             E      at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2375)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2643)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3260)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown
> Source:1)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3203)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:771)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1031)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:125)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:534)
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:503)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1229)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:827)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
> [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@dfc23f4,
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@a07d71d,
> StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@64f9d92, AndroidUiDispatcher@2d4c363]
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.bunkware.bunkyrecipe.ui.recipe.RecipeViewModel>
> has no zero argument constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at
> androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
> ... 71 more

Comment: From where you are providing object of RecipeRepo ? can you add code of it ?
As your error , it looks like Hilt is not able to create instance of RecipeViewModel as it needs RecipeRepo object which may have some issue in providing

Comment: I updated but it was my understanding that RecipeViewModel would inject recipeRepo when it was created and didn't need for it to be provided when creating the instance of it.

Comment: Yes your understanding is right .. so can you try to get viewmodel instance like this 
```val recipeViewModel = hiltViewModel<RecipeViewModel >()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says `RecipeGridScreen` inside your `NavHost` is calling `viewModel()`. As per the [Hilt and Navigation Compose docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation), you must always use [`hiltViewModel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/hilt/navigation/compose/package-summary#hiltViewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String)) when inside a `NavHost` so that Hilt can find the correct factory.

So:

1. Add the `hilt-navigation-compose` dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
```

2. Change all calls to `viewModel()` to `hiltViewModel()`. This is only required inside your `NavHost`, but it works everywhere, so you can do a find/replace of all instances if you'd like.